# Jquery Mobile datepicker event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

Hi Everyone i created an mvc application with datepicker using jquery.For example when i click a particular date the corresponding events on that will be displayed as list.The Following code snippet works fine but when i run the same page using opera mobile emulator the click event was not firing.

```
jquery:
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css

Note:I used the following link as reference

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker/ 

If anyone give the solution,it ll great helpful to me.

@model IEnumerable<WazUpDataServicesMVC4.Model.EventViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Calendar";
  }

 @section Header
  {
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Events")" data-icon="back"  class="ui-btn-    left">Events</a>
 <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>



 <link href="@(Url.Content("~/Content/datepicker.css"))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
  $(function () {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          inline: true,
          //nextText: '&rarr;',
          //prevText: '&larr;',
          showOtherMonths: true,
          //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
          dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
          onSelect: function (date, obj) {
              if (date) {
                  $("#listLayers").find("a:[data-date!='" + date + "']").parent().parent().parent().slideUp();
                  $("#listLayers").find("a:[data-date='" + date + "']").parent().parent().parent().slideDown();
              } else {
                  $("#listLayers").find("a").parent().parent().parent().slideDown();
              }
          }

      });

  });
 </script>
```

}

```
  <div id="datepicker"></div>

  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="listLayers">


  @foreach (var item in Model)


  {
    string display = "none";

    if (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") == item.DateEventTo.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
    {
        display = "block";
    }


        <li style="display:@(display);"> 

            <a data-date="@(item.DateEventTo.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))" class="calendar-link" href="@Url.Action("Events", "Events", new { id = item.EventID,description=item.Description })">
            @item.Description
            </a>

        </li>


   }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that jQuery mobile has used different markup for opera from whatever browser you have tested it on and it was working. I would recommend changing the lines

```
if (date) {
    $("#listLayers").find("a:[data-date!='" + date + "']").parent().parent().parent().slideUp();
    $("#listLayers").find("a:[data-date='" + date + "']").parent().parent().parent().slideDown();
} else {
    $("#listLayers").find("a").parent().parent().parent().slideDown();
}
```

To use the `closest()` function. If you know what element `$("#listLayers").find("a").parent().parent().parent().slideDown();` should be, for example is it a div or has a class or some other known identifier you can use `$("#listLayers").find("a").closest('div')`